# problem with variable value not being correct

Tags: c

I wrote some code for an assignment i have in c. The code does not have any syntax error but the result it prints is wrong and i can't figure out why. I tried assigning the value i wanted to the result variable and print it and it worked fine. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
long kwdikos;
double ethsios_misthos, evdomadiaia_amoivh, amoivh_ana_ora;
int ores_ergasias;

printf("Dwse ton kwdiko: ");
scanf("%ld", &kwdikos);

if (kwdikos >= 1000){
    printf("Dwse ton ethsio mistho: ");
    scanf("%g", &ethsios_misthos);
    evdomadiaia_amoivh = ethsios_misthos / 52;
    printf("H evdomadiaia amoivh einai: %g", evdomadiaia_amoivh);
}
else{
    printf("Dwse tis ores evdomadiaias ergasias: ");
    scanf("%d", &ores_ergasias);
    printf("Dwse thn amoivh ana ora: ");
    scanf("%g",&amoivh_ana_ora);
    if (ores_ergasias > 40){
        evdomadiaia_amoivh = 40 * amoivh_ana_ora + (ores_ergasias - 40) * 1.5 * amoivh_ana_ora;
    }
    else{
        evdomadiaia_amoivh = ores_ergasias * amoivh_ana_ora;
    }
    printf("H evdomadiaia amoivh einai: %g", evdomadiaia_amoivh);
}
return 0;
}
```

I expected evdomadiaia_amoivh to be a number but when i run this code and print it the result is 1.09e something and i dont know why.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can run it and show us what's printed out, and tell us from where is the code behaving not as expected? That's much more helpful than throwing a chunk of code and wishing it to be rectified; that's what you do with a paid service.

Comment: The possible formats to display a floating number are `%f`, `%e` or `%g`. If you do not want the value printed with an exponent (like `1.09e+2`), you must use `%f` not `%g`.

Comment: You need to learn to use a debugger, and also add some intermediate printouts of the results so that you can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: test the result of scanf too

Comment: Thanks it was indeed that i used g instead of lf and f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%g", some_floating_point_value);` prints in fixed point format akin to `"%f"` when the magnitude of the value is neither larger nor small.  It prints in exponential format, akin to `"%e"`, other wise.  Example: 1.09e08

Use `"%f"` or `"%F"` to always print in a fixed point manner.